# How to allow iOS users to set the application's orientation

Tags: ios, user-interface, settings, orientation

I want to add a new setting for orientation to my application, let user choice of Portrait, Landscape, or OS Setting.
I found some solution that need overwrite UIViewController.
Is there a easy way to do it?

I would like to intercept and mock System's orientation change event? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UIApplicationDelegate` method below and return an appropriate mask based on the user's chosen setting:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    // The following conditions are pseudo code to give you an idea
    if "userSetting == portrait" {
        return .portrait
    } else if "userSetting == landscape" {
        return .landscape
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}
```

Also make sure your Info.plist specifies all orientations.

Comment: This work when app start. But it didn't work after user change setting. It's there a way to notify setting change?

Comment: This method never invoke in  iPad simulator. But it work in a real iPad. I'm confusing